# in vim, is there a way to save bookmarks between sessions?

Tags: vim, configuration

when exiting vim and then re-entering, all bookmarks have gone

have found out how to remember last position between files, but not how to remember bookmarks after having exited.

is there a way to configure vim so that bookmarks are remembered for a file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
:set viminfo='1000,f1
```

But note:

> Lowercase marks 'a to 'z are remembered as long as the file remains in
>   the buffer list.  If you remove the file from the buffer list, all its
>   marks are lost.  If you delete a line that contains a mark, that mark
>   is erased.

So you'll need to use uppercase or numeric marks.

See:

- [`:he 21.3`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.3)
- [`:he E20`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#E20)

...for more information.

You may also find [`:mksession`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#%3amksession) useful if you want to save session state.

Comment: after running :mksession same results - Mark not set

Comment: @ccyoung: Ah. I've updated my answer with a note that may help you.

Comment: mea culpa - when first building system ran vim as sudo - ~/.viminfo was given root ownership

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to configure anything.. it's automatically stored in the viminfo file, "File marks" section.

From the manual:

```
'viminfo' 'vi'  
f   Whether file marks need to be stored.  If zero, file marks ('0
        to '9, 'A to 'Z) are not stored.  When not present or when
        non-zero, they are all stored.  '0 is used for the current
        cursor position (when exiting or when doing ":wviminfo").
```

see your settings with `:set vi`

Comment: The defaults are slightly different for some systems. My system default does not include `f`; therefore it requires an extra configuration.