# How to save file marks on VIM?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [in vim, is there a way to save bookmarks between sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958047/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-save-bookmarks-between-sessions)

How to configure VIM to remember file local lower-case marks to the next time VIM is openned?

Comment: Try `mksession` and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958047/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-save-bookmarks-between-sessions

Comment: Yes, or use uppercase marks.