# Keep marks across file reloads in vim

Tags: vim

I have an autocommand for source files that runs an autoformatter on save. If the autoformatter modifies the file, all my marks are lost. Is there a way to preserve the marks in this case? My relevant `.vimrc` configuration is this:

```
function! s:FormatCode()
    if (s:formatOnSave == 1)
        Autoformat
    endif
endfunction
```

Then in an `augroup`:

```
if (executable("clang-format"))
    autocmd FileType c,cpp,objc,objcpp autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> silent! call s:FormatCode()
endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in vim, is there a way to save bookmarks between sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958047/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-save-bookmarks-between-sessions)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the autoformatter is using the *filter* command, this can be done by prepending [`:help :keepmarks`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#:keepmarks) to the command:

```
keepmarks Autoformat
```

Read the caveats in the help. If that doesn't work, you'd have to manually save and restore the marks, e.g. using `getpos()` and `setpos()`.

Comment: It is worth also having a look at `keepjumps` and `keeppatterns`. It's  seems like global commands and execute does not mess with search history. This came in handy on vimscript.